# Notify a windows machine within a network, without username and password

Tags: windows, networking, desktop-application, tcp

The problem statement:

Suppose there are 20 windows machines within a local network. One of the machines serves as the server and hosts the database. Now, the other 19 machines have the access to read from the server machine, but the server machine does not have username and password for any of the other 19 machines.

I have to update a desktop application installed on all the machine. There is a spring-boot application, hosted on the server machine which downloads the build. Now, as soon as I download the build I have to notify all the other 19 machines that build has been downloaded so that they can read and update themselves.

- Solution 1: Install a windows service which will poll the server and check if updates are available.
- Solution 2: Host a POST web API on the 19 machines and notify them by making a post call. I think installing IIS or Tomcat on every machine is not viable.

Is there any other optimal solution for notifying the client?

> Note: We cannot take the RDP and neither have credentials but we can make use of already deployed windows application on the other 19 clients.

Comment: Solution 1 is the usual way. Go for it.

Comment: @Oliver the situation here is that we have to update once in 3 months. And usually, we get a time slot to update like between 1 am to 2 am. Don't you think keeping a windows service that would poll in every 10 mins for a task that is scheduled once in 3 months is overkill?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3: If your machines share the same domain, use msi install packages [to update software all across domain by using Group Policy](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html). It's common way.

Solution 4: Launch desktop application directly from server shared folder. It works good while server machine is always accessible and application is not too heavy for your LAN.

Here you need some care about writing new application files while it running on client computers. Good way is to keep a different folders for different versions and launch with shortcut pointing to latest one:

```
v1.3\app files here
v1.4\app files here
v1.4.6\app files here
v1.7\app files here
app.lnk → v1.7\app.exe
```

client machines launch the application with app.lnk.

*Upd*: if you update application when nobody works (see 1am…2am), you can omit all of this versioning stuff.

Solution 1: It work as well. You can use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to easily launch your update script or exe-file as a Windows service.

Comment: And Solution 5, of course: scheduled launch of update task. See `at` command or [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a windows service or a scheduled task (both could be the same application you provide, but with some arguments). It frequently checks if a new version is available (maybe only once a day).

If you only have a short time frame when the new version has to be installed on all machines you could also provide an installation date with the new version. (Maybe the check will be done through a REST api where the client sends the current installed version number and the server answers with an status code 200 and the body is either empty or provides an json object containing the new version number, the due date and the download url.)

Then the client can already download the new version and make it available on the machine, but it triggers the installation only when the due date is reached. This check of the due date can happen more often, cause all informations are already on the client machine and can be done locally.